# Only eleven coloumns fit in boostrap rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have had this problem in several occasions and I cannot find the reason.

I have a container, a row and a few boxes (divs) in it. I have two boxes in the row, one for the side menu and one for the content. The problem is that as soon as I use a column width of 10 for the content, it is pushed to next row (9 is fine) and the two boxes won't stand side by side (there are of course contents in those boxes). This happens for both normal and fluid containers.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">   
        <div id="module-menu" class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div id="content" class="col-lg-10"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I checked all of the above DIVs (with firebug) to see whether another CSS file overrides something (padding, margin etc.) on them, causing the problem. But apparently no property has been overridden on above DIVs.

Could anyone guess what's wrong and how can I find the problem?

Comment: you will have margins or padding set, this will make the row expand to two rows if there are too many elements/width

Comment: Possible causes: `box-sizing/padding`, `margin`, `display: inline/inline-block; float: none;`

Comment: what about div borders ? even if it 1px it can be the cause of the problem.  Can you give a link to wab site ?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on jsFiddle or something similar?

Comment: @Dima Bootstrap uses `box-sizing: border-box` - padding and border is included to width

Comment: Without seeing the actual code or example, its hard to guess what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead assigning id's and classes to columns make another div inside of them. then you will have a clean grid system that works.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div id="module-menu"></div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```